# recursive how to print the sum of a list

Tags: c#, .net, algorithm, recursion

I am trying to find the sum of a list in a recursive algorithm

**i am learning recursive algorithm, i know i can do it in another way but i am learning**

this is my code (pretty simple)

```
class SumList
{

    public SumList(int[] list ) {
        List<int> listInteger = new List<int>();
        for (int i = 0; i < list.Length; i++)
            listInteger.Add(list[i]);
        sum(listInteger);
    }


    private double sum(List<int> list) {
        if (list.Count == 1)
        {
            return list[0];
        }
        if(list.Count ==2)
        {
            Console.Write(printList(list));
            Console.WriteLine((list[0] + list[1]));
            return list[0] + list[1];
        }
        double last = list[list.Count - 1];
        List<int> backupList = new List<int>(list);
        list.RemoveAt(list.Count -1);
        double s = last + sum(list);
        Console.Write(printList(backupList));
        Console.WriteLine(s);
        return s;
    }
    private string printList(List<int> list)
    {
        string result = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < list.Count; i++)
        {
            result += list[i];
            if (i != list.Count - 1)
            {
                result +="+ ";
            }
            else
            {
                result+= " = ";
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

and this call it like this:

```
int []listInt = new int[] { 4, 5, 6, 7, 9 , 10 };
            new SumList(listInt);
            Console.ReadLine();
```

my problem is that the result is:

[image]

i would like to have the result but like this:

```
4 + 5 + 6 + 7 = ...
4 + 5 + 6 = ...
```

so the results should be printed backwards

**again i do know that there are millinos of way to find the sum of a list, but  am trying to learn recursive algorithsm**

Comment: I really don't know why you downvote, i showed you my efforts. with example results. some users always try to be "cleaver", i wish you said why you downvote

Comment: @jpw there was one downvote but it seems someone upvote again, for the tags, that users could have said that the tags are not correct, he/she could have edited the question. that is why this website is collaborative website, maybe i didn't put the correct type, but i tried what i knew.

Comment: Are you asking how to reverse a list after it's been created or do you wish to create the list in the proper order through a recursive function?

Comment: @DanielHoffmann-Mitscherling printing the list in the proper order using recursie function

Answer (score 2):

As you probably know, a recursive function is a function that calls itself.  This means that in order to solve a problem recursively, we must divide the problem in to steps such that the procedure will not change between steps, but the input to the function will change.  Moreover, if our recursive function is ever to correctly terminate, the problem must get "smaller" with each step we take.  This step represents one **unit of recursion**.  Also, unlike with "normal" iteration, we do not know ahead of time when we are going to reach the end of the problem.  Therefore, we need a mechanism to determine when we have reached the end of the problem and should stop recursing.  This is known as the **base case**.

Let's try your example of finding the sum of a list.

The first thing we must do is come up with a  **unit of recursion** (one abstract step that we can repeat over and over until we find the solution).

We know we have an input type of `List<int>`

In this case we can notice (psuedocode here) that `sum(list) == list[0] + sum(restOfList)`.  Notice that now we have a definite value (`list[0]`) and an object of type `List<int>` (namely `restOfList`).

So, now we have a neat, repeatable procedure.

```
//Idk what language you are using, or if it matters, but I am writing this in java
public int sum(List<Integer> list) {
  //still need a base case
  return  list.get(0) + sum(list.subList(1, list.size()));
}
```

Now we only need to determine the **base case**.  So we need to determine when we will have gone through all the elements of the list.

For this let's run through a few steps to see what will happen.  Let's start with the following list: `{1, 2, 3, 4}`

```
sum({1, 2, 3, 4}) 
-> 1 + sum({2, 3, 4})
       -> 2 + sum({3, 4})
              -> 3 + sum({4})
                     -> 4 + oops!!!
```

Clearly, we cannot get the sublist beginning at index 1 from a list of size 1.  This gives us the answer for what our base case should be.

```
public int sum(List<Integer> list) {
  printList(list);
  //base case
  if (list.size() == 1)
    return list.get(0); //recall that this is the entire list
  //otherwise, continue to next step.
  return  list.get(0) + sum(list.subList(1, list.size()));
}
```

The addition works because the return statement of the first step is dependent on the return statement of the second step and so on.  This is also why the steps will print in reverse order.

Just for clarity, let's trace through it one final time.

```
sum({1, 2, 3, 4}) //sum({1, 2, 3, 4}) is called from main()
-> 1 + sum({2, 3, 4}) //sum({2, 3, 4}) is called from sum({1, 2, 3, 4})
       -> 2 + sum({3, 4}) //sum({3, 4}) is called from sum({2, 3, 4})
              -> 3 + sum({4}) //sum({4}) is called from sum({3, 4})
                     <- 4 //sum({4}) returns 4 to sum({3, 4})
                 3 + 4
              <- 7 //sum({3, 4}) returns 7 to sum({2, 3, 4})
          2 + 7
       <- 9 //sum({2, 3, 4}) returns 9 to sum({1, 2, 3, 4}) 
   1 + 9
<- 10 //sum({1, 2, 3, 4}) returns 10
```

I hope this helped make things a little bit clearer.

Answer (score 2):

Or try this

```
 public static int Sum(List<int> listOfInt)
    {
        if (listOfInt.Count == 1)
        {
            return Convert.ToInt32(listOfInt[0]);

        }
        else
        {
            return Convert.ToInt32(listOfInt[0]) + Sum(listOfInt.Skip(1).ToList());


        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, this is not how I would do it, and it definitely has a number of oddities.  But if I try to preserve the spirit behind your design, then I think a good way to accomplish this is by buffering the output in a `StringBuilder`, and using its `Insert(0, str)` method to place the lines in the right place.

```
  public SumList(int[] list)
  {
     List<int> listInteger = new List<int>();
     for (int i = 0; i < list.Length; i++)
        listInteger.Add(list[i]);

     StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();
     sum(listInteger, output);
     Console.WriteLine(output.ToString());
  }

  private double sum(List<int> list, StringBuilder output)
  {
     if (list.Count == 1)
     {
        return list[0];
     }
     if (list.Count == 2)
     {
        output.Append(printList(list));
        output.Append((list[0] + list[1])).Append(Environment.NewLine);
        return list[0] + list[1];
     }

     double last = list[list.Count - 1];
     List<int> backupList = new List<int>(list);
     list.RemoveAt(list.Count - 1);
     double s = last + sum(list, output);
     output.Insert(0, Environment.NewLine);
     output.Insert(0, s);
     output.Insert(0, printList(backupList));
     return s;
  }

  private string printList(List<int> list)
  {
     string result = "";
     for (int i = 0; i < list.Count; i++)
     {
        result += list[i];
        if (i != list.Count - 1)
        {
           result += " + ";
        }
        else
        {
           result += " = ";
        }
     }
     return result;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code works by calculating the sums of all of the lists (and decreasing the lists as it goes) and then printing them going backwards, which explains why the lists you see are increasing in size. The way to fix this is by fixing your recursion. In order to have them printing in decreasing order, you want your recursion to go in increasing order. So, calculate sum(List.subList(1)), then sum(List.subList(2)), and so on...

An alternative quick fix is to save the output as a strings in an array and just print the array backwards.

Comment: Also, I don't suppose that that's java code, since it doesn't compile as java code, so you should probably remove that tag.

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution is

```
List<int> listInteger = new List<int> ();

public SumList (int[] list)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < list.Length; i++)
        listInteger.Add (list [i]);
    listInteger.Reverse();
}

private void sumR (List<int> list, int index)
{
    int sigma = 0;
    if (list.Count - 1 == index) {
        return;// sigma + list [index];
    } else {
        for (int i = list.Count-1; i>=index; i--) {
            sigma += list [i];
            if (i == list.Count - 1)
                Console.Write ("{0} ", list [i]);
            else
                Console.Write ("+ {0} ", list [i]);
        }
        Console.WriteLine ("= {0}", sigma);
        sumR (list, index + 1);
    }
}
public void doSum(){
    sumR(listInteger, 0);
}
```

There is no need for other methods, though you can call sumR from constructor if you like. Test is

```
int [] listInt = new int[] { 4, 5, 6, 7, 9 , 10 };
SumList sl = new SumList (listInt);
sl.doSum();
Console.ReadLine ();
```

Output is:

```
4 + 5 + 6 + 7 + 9 + 10 = 41
4 + 5 + 6 + 7 + 9 = 31
4 + 5 + 6 + 7 = 22
4 + 5 + 6 = 15
4 + 5 = 9
```

Answer (score 0):

The recursive function:

```
public static void PrintSum(int[] list)
{
    // Define the end of the recursion 
    if (list.Count() > 2)
        // Copy the shorter list to PrintSum()
        PrintSum(list.Take(list.Count() - 1).ToArray());

    // Print the result of list AFTER shorter list is done
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(
        string.Format("{0} = {1}", string.Join("+ ", list), 
        list.Sum()));
}

public static void PrintSumReverse(int[] list)
{
    // Print the result of list
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(
        string.Format("{0} = {1}", string.Join("+ ", list),
        list.Sum()));

    // Define the end of the recursion
    if (list.Count() > 2)
        // Copy the shorter list to PrintSum()
        PrintSum(list.Take(list.Count() - 1).ToArray());
}
```

Usage:

```
var listInt = new int[] { 4, 5, 6, 7, 9, 10 };

PrintSum(listInt);

/* Result:

    4+ 5 = 9
    4+ 5+ 6 = 15
    4+ 5+ 6+ 7 = 22
    4+ 5+ 6+ 7+ 9 = 31
    4+ 5+ 6+ 7+ 9+ 10 = 41
*/


PrintSumReverse(listInt);

/* Result
    4+ 5+ 6+ 7+ 9+ 10 = 41
    4+ 5+ 6+ 7+ 9 = 31
    4+ 5+ 6+ 7 = 22
    4+ 5+ 6 = 15
    4+ 5 = 9
*/
```